# Windows Server 2012 : The request to list features available on the specified server failed

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to add a Role in Windows 2012 Server manager , and I get this error message

```
The request to list features available on the specified server failed.
```

[image]

Comment: Might be better off posting this on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: thanks , I have done so